# Passing arguments correctly to FourierTransform

Tags: function-construction, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to define the functional $T$ on test functions $f$ and $g$ in Mathematica 11, where $$T(f,g) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(x)\hat{g}(-x)\,dx$$
So I have written:

```
T[f_Symbol, g_Symbol] := Integrate[FourierTransform[f[s], s, x] * FourierTransform[g[s], s, -x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Then, I define (for example) the functions

```
f[s_]:= Exp[-s^2];
g[s_]:= 2*s*Exp[-s^2];
```

I can successfully evaluate the command `T[f,f]`, but when I try to evaluate `T[f,g]`, I get the error `General: -x is not a valid variable`. I suspect that this is some assignment issue involving `:=`, but I don't know where to start when troubleshooting this. What is going on here?

Comment: @chuy That was also my first thought but `FourierTransform[f[s], s, -x]` is evaluated successfully without errors.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm trying to _not_ introduce conjugates into this calculation, because the functions I want to use this with have a number of other parameters and building a `Refine` or `ComplexExpand` command into all this makes it take quite a while.

Comment: @chuy Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g$ is of the form $g(s) = s \, h(s)$, we have $\hat g(\xi) = \pm \operatorname{i} \tfrac{\partial}{\partial \xi} \hat h(\xi)$. If the Fourier transform of $h$ is known (as it is in this case; $h$ is basically the Gaussian bell function), this is the method of choice to compute the Fourier transform. $\xi$ is the third argument of `FourierTransform`, so Mathematica uses $\xi = - x$ and this is why it tries to evaluate `D[1/(Sqrt[2]*E^(x^2/4)), {-x, 1}]` since this is $\tfrac{\partial \hat h(-x)}{\partial (-x)}$. And `D` needs `Symbol`s in the second argument for operation. But `-x` (`Minus[x]` in `InputForm`) has the head `Minus` and is thus not treated as `Symbol`, thus the error message.

The following seems to circumvent this:

```
T[f_Symbol, g_Symbol] := Integrate[
  FourierTransform[f[s], s, x] (FourierTransform[g[s], s, y] /. y -> -x),
  {x, -∞, ∞}]
T[f, g]
```

> 0

Seems to be correct because the integrant is an odd function.

Comment: Wow, I used the wrong syntax when I tried this before posting, and consequently ruled it out too hastily. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Actually, this behavior is a bit subtle, so I wouldn't have expected it upfront. It's really not obvious that the syntax is wrong.